# How to make the floating label under the text in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android

The TextInputLayout widget support floating label for EditText(check this post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)), but default the floating label is above the text.

[image]

But I want to make the label under the text like this, how to do it???

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) library. It has label below the edit text namely helper text.

Answer (score 1):

Refer  Android Floating Label EditText

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-floating-label-edittext/